# Python - Return values from a function

Tags: python

I have this config file:

```
[test]
one: value1
two: value2
```

This function return items, values from section test of config file, but when I call the function only return first item (one, value1).

```
def getItemsAvailable(section):
    for (item, value) in config.items(section):
        return (item, value)
```

I call the getItemsAvailable() with this function:

```
def test():
    item, value = getItemsAvailable('test')
    print (item, value)
```

I guess that I should create a list on getItemsAvailable() function, and return the list for read the values on test() function, true?

Any suggestions?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension. Change

```
for (item, value) in config.items(section):
    # the function returns at the end of the 1st iteration
    # hence you get only 1 tuple. 
    # You may also consider using a generator & 'yield'ing the tuples
    return (item, value)
```

to

```
return [(item, value) for item, value in config.items(section)]
```

And concerning your `test()` function:

```
def test():
    aList = getItemsAvailable('test')
    print (aList)
```

Comment: Hey, very nice solution. Thanks!! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use a generator function:

```
def getItemsAvailable(section):
    for (item, value) in config.items(section):
        yield (item, value)
```

And get the items like this:

```
def test():
    for item, value in getItemsAvailable('test'):
        print (item, value)
```

Comment: Wow, I think that I will write this on my code. Tanks!!